# How to show gratitude for employers esteem towards employee

Tags: gifts

When having a company and superiors expressing esteem towards their employees (gifts, congratulations, cards), how to react?

This is my first year working for the company (simple specialist position) and I don't know how to react to this:

- present (worth 500 dollars) to all employees for the compay's success and corona crisis
- congratulation card at the end of trial period + sucessful degree
- snacks sent home for Easter/Christmas during lockdown
- pay rise (low, but without asking)
- 3 bottles of wine for christmas (I had a lot overwork this year, but they didn't need to)
- very kind Christmas card thanking me for my effort

Of course, at work there is always an "intent" but they are also not obliged to. And I don't want them to think I take it for granted. What's a smart way to react/show gratitude?

Answer (score 4):

> Thanks

^ like that :)

Seriously, you can thank whomever is the appropriate point of contact when you receive the goods. If (as it sounds) you are wanting to show appreciation for multiple things over the last few months you can just tell your immediate manager that you appreciate what the company has done, either verbally or via e-mail, whichever you feel more comfortable with.

Comment: Yeah really.  "Say thanks, and feel valued."

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to show gratitude, do two things:

- Say "Thanks", as and when possible, extend the kindness. Be approachable, be helpful.
- Put some extra efforts, as and when possible, to go the extra mile over and above your assigned work to show that, you also care. Show them, they put their faith on right people - learn a new skill, take up a new responsibility, start a new process for productivity improvement - it could be just anything which benefits the team and the company. Consider it as a return-gift from you.